# How do I import a fbx file into blender from command line?

Tags: python, scripting, import, file-format, command-line

I would like to import a fbx file (3Ds Max scene file) and save the project from the command line, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You simply need one operator to import the FBX, and another operator to export the blendfile. Replace the filepath variables with the actual paths you want to use.

```
# Import FBX
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx( filepath = yourFBXfilePath )

# Export blend file
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile( filepath = yourBlendFilePath )
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: "TypeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx" error, expected a string enum in ('INVOKE_DEFAULT', 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN', 'INVOKE_REGION_CHANNELS', 'INVOKE_REGION_PREVIEW', 'INVOKE_AREA', 'INVOKE_SCREEN', 'EXEC_DEFAULT', 'EXEC_REGION_WIN', 'EXEC_REGION_CHANNELS', 'EXEC_REGION_PREVIEW', 'EXEC_AREA', 'EXEC_SCREEN')"

Comment: here is my python script

Comment: import sys
import os
import bpy

blend_dir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
if blend_dir not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(blend_dir)
# Import FBX
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx( "D:\test.fbx" )

# Export blend file
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile( "D:\test.html" )

Comment: Did you use the `filepath` keyword argument? This is the kind of error you would get if you'd just run `bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx( 'MYPATH' )` instead of `bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx( filepath = 'MYPATH' )`.

Comment: As I thought :)
Make sure to use the `filepath` argument for both operators.